`NSWorkspace.open` fails with error `The application “TextEdit.app” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred.`
I am trying to use NSWorkspace.open(_:withApplicationAt:configuration:completionHandler:) to open the currently open document in my document based SwiftUI app.

Clicking on the button shown in the screenshot is supposed to open the file Test.exampletext in TextEdit.
For this, I created a new document based macOS app for which I am getting the url of the currently opened document by using FocusedValueKey. (which actually works beautifully …)
The issue is though that I cannot seem to be able to open that file in another application. I am trying to open the same file in TextEdit.
The function I implemented for this looks like this:
func openFile(with url: URL) {
    guard 
      let texteditURL = URL(string: "/System/Applications/TextEdit.app"),
      FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: texteditURL.absoluteString)
    else {
      AppLogger.standard.debug("Could not get url for app TextEdit.")
      return
    }
    let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
    configuration.activates = true
    configuration.allowsRunningApplicationSubstitution = true
    configuration.hidesOthers = true
    configuration.promptsUserIfNeeded = true
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(
      [url],
      withApplicationAt: texteditURL,
      configuration: configuration
    ) { _, error in
        if let error {
          AppLogger.standard.error("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
  }

This errors with the message of The application “TextEdit.app” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred.
A few things come to mind:

Sandboxing and access right issues
I am missing/not setting something correct in NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration
TextEdit does not want to open it cause the file is already opened and perhaps locked by my app?

How can I get around this/what am I missing? My real use case btw. is that I have an app that creates a Deckset compatible markdown file and I want to be able to open the currently editing file in Deckset.
What I can say is that

the file exists
the url for TextEdit is correct
I can open the file in TextEdit manually (even with my app running, which should rule out point 2. above …)

Here's all the code:
import OSLog
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

//MARK: App entry point
@main
struct poc_UrlOfOpenedDocumentApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    DocumentGroup(newDocument: poc_UrlOfOpenedDocumentDocument()) { file in
      ContentView(document: file.$document)
        .focusedSceneValue(
          \.fileURL,
           {
             if let url = file.fileURL {
               AppLogger.standard.debug("File url at app start is: \(url.description)")
               return Binding { url } set: { _ in }
             }
             AppLogger.standard.warning("URL is unknown …")
             return nil
           }()
        )
    }
  }
}

//MARK: Content View
struct ContentView: View {
  @FocusedValue(\.fileURL) var fileUrl
  @Binding var document: poc_UrlOfOpenedDocumentDocument

  var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $document.text)
    Text(fileUrl?.wrappedValue.debugDescription ?? "n/a")
      .onAppear {
        AppLogger.standard.debug("URL is (onAppear): \(fileUrl?.wrappedValue.description ?? "n/a")")
      }
    Button("Open in TextEdit") {
      guard let fileUrl
      else {
        AppLogger.standard.warning("There is currently no file url.")
        return
      }
      AppLogger.standard.debug("URL is (Button): \(fileUrl.wrappedValue.absoluteString)")
      openFile(with: fileUrl.wrappedValue)
    }
    .padding(.bottom)
  }

  //MARK: **** Open file logic ****
  func openFile(with url: URL) {
    guard 
      let texteditURL = URL(string: "/System/Applications/TextEdit.app"),
      FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: texteditURL.absoluteString)
    else {
      AppLogger.standard.debug("Could not get url for app TextEdit.")
      return
    }
    let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
    configuration.activates = true
    configuration.allowsRunningApplicationSubstitution = true
    configuration.hidesOthers = true
    configuration.promptsUserIfNeeded = true
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(
      [url],
      withApplicationAt: texteditURL,
      configuration: configuration
    ) { _, error in
        if let error {
          AppLogger.standard.error("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
  }
}

//MARK: Preview
#Preview {
  ContentView(document: .constant(poc_UrlOfOpenedDocumentDocument()))
}

//MARK: FocuseValues definition
extension FocusedValues {
  struct DocumentFocusedValues: FocusedValueKey {
    typealias Value = Binding<URL>
  }

  var fileURL: Binding<URL>? {
    get {
      self[DocumentFocusedValues.self]
    }
    set {
      self[DocumentFocusedValues.self] = newValue
    }
  }
}

//MARK: AppLogger
enum AppLogger {
  private static let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier

  static let standard = Logger(subsystem: bundleID  ?? "", category: "default")
}

//MARK: Document definitions
extension UTType {
  static var exampleText: UTType {
    UTType(importedAs: "com.example.plain-text")
  }
}

struct poc_UrlOfOpenedDocumentDocument: FileDocument {
  var text: String
  var fileURL: URL?

  init(
    text: String = "Hello, world!"
  ) {
    self.text = text
  }

  static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.exampleText] }

  init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
    guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
          let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    else {
      throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
    }
    text = string
  }

  func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
    let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
    return .init(regularFileWithContents: data)
  }
}

